How to handle changes in stateful streaming query in a production environment?
We have a streaming job running on EMR which is polling Kafka, aggregating the events for a certain window and then pushing the output to S3.
We need to add some new fields in the kafka events, that would be then part of the groupBy clause in the streaming query and should also be present in the output.
As per spark documentation any changes in streaming query cannot use the same checkpoint directory.
So one way is to clear out/change the checkpoint directory. But would that not cause re-processing of some of the events from Kafka leading to duplicates in aggregation?
What would be the best way to handle this?
One solution I tried by running two builds parallely and switching to the new build when the output became same from both.
